# Compute unique axis labels according to gps data in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a file with gps coordinates and a scalar value measured from a
bus following some route. I would like to produce a plot with distance
travelled on the x-axis and the the scalar value plotted along the
y-axis.  I would like to label the x-axis with kilometers and also
with labels indicating the busstops I am interested in.

To illustrate the problem here is some code to make a MWE for a
similar problem where a bus is travelling in a triangular route with
corners `A`, `B` and `C` at xy-coordinates `[0,0]`, `[0,1]`, `[1,0]`. The bus is
travelling in a loop `A-->B-->C-->A..` etc. The scalar value is `x+y`
i.e. the sum of the coordiate positions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

n = 30
L = 1.0

def generate_route(num_loops):
    """Generates x,y coordinates and scalar value x+y for bus travelling A->B->C num_loop times."""
    def get_perturb():
        return float(np.random.rand(1)[0] * 0.5*(L/n))       
    x = []
    y = []
    for l in range(num_loops):
        # A to B
        x += [0.0] * n
        y += [i*L/float(n) for i in range(0,n)]
        # B to C
        x += [i*L/float(n) for i in range(0,n)]
        y += [1.0-i*L/float(n) for i in range(0,n)]
        # C to A
        x += [1.0 - i*L/float(n) for i in range(0,n)]
        y += [0.0] * n
    x = map(lambda i: i + get_perturb(), x)
    y = map(lambda i: i + get_perturb(), y)
    val = map(lambda i: i[0]+i[1], zip(x,y))
    return [x, y, val]

x, y, val = generate_route(3)

# put data into DataFrame
d = {'x':x,'y':y,'val':val}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index = pd.date_range(dt.datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0),periods=len(x),freq='1s'))

# plot route
plt.figure()
df.plot(x='x', y='y',xlim=[-0.1,1.1],ylim=[-0.1,1.1])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title('Route: x vs y')

# plot bus stops
stops = {'A':[0.,0.], 'B':[0.,1.], 'C':[1.,0.]}
ax.plot(stops['A'][0], stops['A'][1], 'r.', markersize=20)
ax.plot(stops['B'][0], stops['B'][1], 'g.', markersize=20)
ax.plot(stops['C'][0], stops['C'][1], 'y.', markersize=20)
# plt.savefig('route.png')

# compute distance travelled as sum of line segments connecting adjacent readings
df = pd.concat([df,df[['x','y']].rename(columns={'x':'x_prev','y':'y_prev'},copy=True).shift(1)],axis=1).dropna()
df['Dist'] = np.sqrt((df['x']-df['x_prev'])**2 + (df['y']-df['y_prev'])**2)
df['TotalDist'] = df['Dist'].cumsum(0)

# plot value with distance
plt.figure()
df.plot(x='TotalDist', y='val')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title('TotalDist vs val')
# plt.savefig('totaldistvsval.png')
plt.show()
```

Output figures:

[image: route]
[image: totaldistvsval]

Now I get stuck, I would like to add bus-stop labels along the x-axis
on the `TotalDist vs val` plot e.g. labelled vertical lines or
similar.  I have the following code to label each row of the DataFrame
with the stop it is close to.  One problem is that many rows will
match each so I need to pick just one in each set and then I need to use that
to add labels to the x-axis.

```
def label_stops(row):
    def close(p,q):
        return np.sqrt((p[0]-q[0])**2+(p[1]-q[1])**2) < 3.0*(L/n)
    res = 'None'
    for name, loc in stops.iteritems():
        if close([row['x'], row['y']], loc):
            res = name
    return res
df['label'] = df.apply(label_stops, axis = 1)
df
```

Which gives the following which is some progress:

```
                          val         x         y    x_prev    y_prev      Dist  TotalDist label
2014-09-07 14:57:17  0.046516  0.008194  0.038322  0.014114  0.001992  0.036809   0.036809     A
2014-09-07 14:57:18  0.084732  0.014400  0.070333  0.008194  0.038322  0.032607   0.069416     A
2014-09-07 14:57:19  0.122984  0.013296  0.109688  0.014400  0.070333  0.039370   0.108786  None
2014-09-07 14:57:20  0.154545  0.005306  0.149240  0.013296  0.109688  0.040351   0.149137  None
...                       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...        ...   ...
2014-09-07 14:57:42  0.882114  0.007021  0.875094  0.009029  0.839339  0.035811   0.888190  None
2014-09-07 14:57:43  0.923723  0.015505  0.908218  0.007021  0.875094  0.034194   0.922383     B
2014-09-07 14:57:44  0.952783  0.014462  0.938320  0.015505  0.908218  0.030121   0.952504     B
2014-09-07 14:57:45  0.985179  0.009943  0.975237  0.014462  0.938320  0.037192   0.989696     B
2014-09-07 14:57:46  1.010307  0.007226  1.003080  0.009943  0.975237  0.027976   1.017672     B
...                       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...        ...   ...
2014-09-07 15:01:16  1.011478  1.001009  0.010469  0.970733  0.042690  0.044214   9.412063     C
2014-09-07 15:01:17  0.968017  0.967922  0.000095  1.001009  0.010469  0.034676   9.446738     C
2014-09-07 15:01:19  0.921621  0.907178  0.014444  0.934321  0.008302  0.027829   9.509157     C
2014-09-07 15:01:20  0.876492  0.875172  0.001320  0.907178  0.014444  0.034592   9.543749  None
2014-09-07 15:01:21  0.862456  0.846593  0.015863  0.875172  0.001320  0.032066   9.575814  None
...                       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...        ...   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following which works fine but is probably not idiomatic.

```
# loop over rows with label column not equal to 'None',
# collect consecutive rows with same location into a
# list (grp) and return list of those lists (groups)
groups = []
grp = []
df1 = df[df['label'] != 'None']
prev = df1.iloc[0]['label']
for r in df1.iterrows():
    curr = r[1]['label']
    if curr == prev:
        grp.append(r[1])
    else:
        groups.append(grp)
        grp = []
        prev = curr

# extract stop locations get middle distances
loclines = []
for g in groups:
    mids = g[len(g)/2]
    loclines.append([mids['TotalDist'], mids['label']])

# mark stops on plot as coloured vertical lines
plt.figure()
df.plot(x='TotalDist', y='val')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title('TotalDist vs val')
for li, l in enumerate(loclines):
    if loclines[li][1] == 'A': color = 'r'
    if loclines[li][1] == 'B': color = 'g'
    if loclines[li][1] == 'C': color = 'y'
    plt.axvline(x=loclines[li][0],color= color)

plt.show()
```

Resulting figure:

[image]